# How to handle exceptions in Java in functional way

Tags: java, functional-programming

How to handle exceptions in Java in functional way?

If I do:

```
try{
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   //log it
   // throw exception? 
}
```

and catching the exceptions, what should I return:

1. Throw the exception?
2. Else send some error code ( similar to how we handle in C languages )

   Because functional programming says:

> A function should always return the same type.

Given this scenario, it becomes for certain given input it will throw the exception. Hence its not a pure functional style.

How one should handle this case in Java?

Comment: Instead of `same value`, did you want to say `same type` ?

Comment: @Dici: Ya correct, I want the same

Comment: I meant that a function almost never return a single value (would it even be useful ?). I edited it in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well even in functional programming, exceptions are not considered as return values.

Take for instance, this segment of SML code:

```
fun remove_card (cs, c, e) =
    case cs of
    [] => raise e (* raise exception and stop execution of the function *) 
     | x::xs => if x = c 
           then xs 
           else  x::remove_card (xs,c,e)
```

As you can see, when the exception is raised, we forget about the original return type of the function (a list). It is in this moment that an error situation has happened in your application and you want to handle it to avoid your application from crashing. So, you would not be breaking the purity of your functional programming, since exceptions are thrown, not returned, in order to handle the instability caused by unexpected values/behavior inside your application.

Answer (score -1):

Don't both log and rethrow, if you feel like you want to put some information down and rethrow then wrap the exception. Log only if you are done dealing with this exception and plan on returning a value from the method. Not some error indication like in C, actual value. For example you tried to download something but failed, however you still have a fallback. If you are trying to indicate an error you throw an exception.

Just to add, a lot of times people deal with exceptions by logging in place and returning a null. In the vast majority of cases this is the wrong thing to do as it will only lead to frustration of dealing with NPEs in completely different places